# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change the header background when scrolling, but the problem is there that react doesn't know `addEventListener`.

If I change `window` to `document`  there is not any error but the `console.log(window.scrolly)` is undefined.

This is all code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, window, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navbar, NavDropdown, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import classes from "../../styles/header.module.css";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";
export default function header() {
const [transparentHeader, setHeader] = useState(false);

const listenScrollEvent = () => {
console.log(window.scrollY);
};

useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);

return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", listenScrollEvent);
}, []);

//

return (
<Fragment>
  <Navbar expand="md" fixed="top" className={transparentHeader}>
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
        <img src="/header.png"></img>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Nav.Link className={classes.navlink} href="/">
            Home
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing" className={classes.navlink}>
            About
          </Nav.Link>
          <NavDropdown
            title="Services"
            id="collasible-nav-dropdown"
            className={classes.services}
          >
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
              Another action
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
              Something
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
              Separated link
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <NavDropdown
            title="Pages"
            id="collasible-nav-dropdown"
            className={classes.services}
          >
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
              Another action
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
              Something
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
              Separated link
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <NavDropdown
            title="Blogs"
            id="collasible-nav-dropdown"
            className={classes.services}
          >
            <Icon icon="bx:bx-chevron-down" />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
              Another action
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
              Something
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
              Separated link
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing" className={classes.navlink}>
            Contact
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link
            href="#deets"
            className={(classes.navlink, classes.headerSearch)}
          >
            <Icon icon="bi:search" />
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link
            href="#memes"
            className={(classes.navlink, classes.SignIn)}
          >
            Iign In
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
</Fragment>
);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Nextjs or some SSR framework?

Comment: I am using Nextjs

Comment: It should not be an issue if you place it inside `useEffect` are you sure you don't have `window.addEventListener` somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that

Comment: I added all my code

Comment: I  added an answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `window` from React, it is already available in the browser environment:

So remove window:

**import React, { Fragment, useState, <s>window</s>, useEffect } from "react";**